# How to add a branch from the repository to the branch of another repository

Tags: android, git

I have the following situation, namely I have 2 remote repositories: A, which is a project, and B, which is a library. Each of the repositories, as you know, has the master branch, but also additional branches, let's assume A has X and B has Y. I downloaded both repositories and how can I now locally to repository A (project) to branch X add repository B (library) Y branch?

Comment: Git isn't really about *branches* but rather about *commits*. You could import some or all of the commits from repository B to repository A, but that's usually a bad idea; consider submodules, as [Mike answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942116/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

Use Git Submodules. To get you started: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

It's like operating a repository with a main module (your project) and a submodule (your library)